# VS 2008 Intellisense hanging on right click

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, freeze

I have a fairly large C++ solution in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. When I RIGHT CLICK, I see the updating intellisense in the status bar and the whole studio freezes for several minutes.

Right click worked fine in 2005.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating intellisense on larger projects just kills productivity - Visual Assist is a much better replacement.  I think though that intellisense is also linked to the way VS parses the code for the designer, so a more temporary solution to test with is to replace your .ncb file with a folder called [solution].ncb

I highly recommend Visual Assist though

Answer (score 4):

Delete you ncb files, and let them regenerate. This how we usually workaround intellisense when it is behaving badly. It akes a bit to regenerate but it is worth it.

Comment: this works frequently. I heartily recommend trying this first

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense is known to kill over on large C++ projects.  The only reliable solution I have found (despite their attempts to hotfix) is to disable Intellisense by removing/renaming `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\feacp.dll`.

Luckily, an add-on like Visual Assist is quite the superior replacement to Intellisense, I find.