# Visual Studio 2008 Find dialog takes >2s to appear

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason my Visual Studio Find dialog, which usually shows instantly after I press Ctrl+F, has started to take more than 2 seconds to show. During this time Visual Studio is entirely unresponsive.

2 seconds for a small window to show is outrageous :) Restarting VS or rebooting the machine didn't help. Has anyone seen this before? How can I fix this?

**OS**: Vista x64; **Defrag**: Weekly, at night

Comment: Operating system?  Do you defrag your hard drive regularily?

Comment: It is not the size of the window that matters, but the work it is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Heh, of course it is, that was a joke :) However, 2 seconds of work to show a Find dialog - that's too much. Besides, it has always used to show instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by reinstalling Visual Studio.

P.S. This has happened again; here's what I observed this time:

- Visual Studio was running when a major disk defrag occurred.
- Halfway through the major disk defrag the UI (and the Find dialog in particular) started taking a long time to appear. During the slowdowns the Visual Studio process spends a lot of CPU time in the kernel (according to ProcExp)
- A Windows Update was pending.
- Restarting Visual Studio did not help fix the problem.
- Applying the windows update and restarting the OS fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use ctrl-f3. You just position your cursor on the word you want to find, and it will allow you to step through each occurance by pressing f3

Edit: Another option would be to dock the find dialog - so it doesn't require closing and reopening.

Comment: That works until I need to use different search options or replace... (replace is also just as slow now).

Comment: You know you can dock the find dialog, that way you dont have to open it at all.

Answer (score 2):

It must be Aero mode, which causes the problem:

Here is my timing:

- Launch VS 2008 on Win7.
- Once GUI is launched, press Ctrl+F
- Find dialog takes about 5 seconds to fully paint. During this time the entire VS window is repainted several times and very slowly, blinking and flashing like crazy.
- Close VS
- Right click on devenv.exe -> Properties -> Compatibility. Check either "Disable Visual Scenes" or "Disable display composition". Press OK.
- launch VS 2008.
- Once GUI is launched, press Ctrl+F.
- Find dialog takes about 1 second to fully paint itself.

Comment: just checked it, on VS 2010 this is not the source of the problem. The Find & Replace dialog still needs 5 seconds to load, on my 8-core iMac with SSD

Answer (score 1):

While your issue is very specific and would be hard to answer, without a lot more detail.

Look through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) on optimizing Visual Studio.

If these don't speed it up, I would look to Microsoft for support.

Comment: The question you linked is very useful and I had done most of those things a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I find that intellisense drains a lot of resources. Since I don't need it (using [Visual Assist X](http://wholetomato.com/)) I disabled it. 
Also see this StackOverflow  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778372/vs-2008-intellisense-hanging-on-right-click) containing more info.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) (free add-on) has a useful 'Quick Find' feature that tracks down line numbers, text matches, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the project's .ncb file?  It's where VS stores Intellisense data and it seems to just grow forever as the project changes.  It will be automatically recreated by VS without all the cruft if you just delete it.

Comment: This is a C# project, so no .ncb file. C# intellisense works rather well overall, I have to say, compared to C++.